# How to check that all variables inside a python function are local?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, scope, global-variables

Given a Python function definition, is there some tool that can check that all variables used inside the function are local (either passed in as a parameter or declared within the function)?

Comment: Why do you want to perform such a check? Names bound to built-in functions (such as `print`) and imported modules (such as `math`) are typically non-local anyway.

Comment: @GodIsOne I ended up using an IDE that highlights non-local variables

Answer (score 0):

To get all the local variables you can use `dir()`:

e.g.

```
def func(a,b):
    name='John'
    city='New York'
    age=33

    #to print all the local variables inside this function.
    print(dir())
    
func(2,3)

#output
['a', 'age', 'b', 'city', 'name']
```

You can also use `locals()`:

```
def func(a,b):
    name='John'
    city='New York'
    age=33

    #to print all the local variables inside this function.
    print(locals())
    
func(2,3)

#output
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'name': 'John', 'city': 'New York', 'age': 33}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The indentation is best feature in python so when the function , loop or any other is used in python we get single tab as indent from left so we can know about local and global variables in python


a=10

def func(a,b):
    name='John'
    city='New York'
    age=33

    #to print all the local variables inside this function.
    print(dir())
    
func(2,3)

#output
['a', 'age', 'b', 'city', 'name']




In the above code the a=10 is global and the a inside the function parenthesis is local.
```